# Getting error while updating pip in Docker container being built

Tags: python, docker, pip, containers, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, one step is to upgrade the pip i.e.

`RUN pip install --upgrade pip`

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM centos:7.2.1511


RUN yum install -y epel-release && yum repolist
RUN yum install -y python-pip python-devel
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN yum install -y --enablerepo=epel httpd mod_wsgi openldap-devel mariadb-devel yum-plugin-ovl git
RUN yum install -y gcc

VOLUME ["/var/www/website.com/"]
WORKDIR /var/www/website.com/

ADD requirements/ requirements/
RUN pip install -i http://local.pypi:8080/root/pypi/ --trusted-host local-web-test01 -r requirements/base.txt -v

RUN rm /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
ADD conf/website.com.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
#Config for git clone permissions
ADD conf/.ssh/ /usr/share/httpd/.ssh/
RUN chown apache:apache -R /usr/share/httpd/.ssh/
RUN chmod 600 /usr/share/httpd/.ssh/id_rsa

VOLUME ["/var/www/website.com/static"]
```

When it reaches the above step it ends up with below error, I do not know why it is happening.

The path `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches` I believe exists inside the container, and I don't understand why it having something in directory ends up in error.

```
 ---> Running in 9c255c769abc
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Removing intermediate container 9c255c769abc
Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: Can you post the full Dockerfile?

Comment: Most probably you don't have enough privileges to perform the upgrade - are you root in that step? But anyway, you shouldn't use `pip` to upgrade/modify packages managed by your system - you should invoke the distro's package manager (`apt update && apt upgrade -y python3-pip` for Debian-based distros, `yum update && yum install -y python-pip` for RHEL/CentOS, etc).

Comment: This is centos 7 , I did wanted to install latest version of  pip right away rather than having to upgrade

Comment: @KlausD. I havea dded dockerfile.